# How to validate if value is an array using Zend_Filter_Input?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend performs validation for Zend_Filter_Input recursively, so the code:

```
    $data = array(
        'update' => array(1, 2, 3)
    );

    $validators = array(
        'update' => array(
            new Zend_Validate_Callback('is_array'),
            'presence' => 'required'
        )
    );

    $filter = new Zend_Filter_Input(array(), $validators, $data);
    var_dump($filter->isValid());
    var_dump($filter->getMessages());
```

returns `false` and messages that 1, 2 and 3 aren't valid values.

Any ways to validate if a value is array, without recursive rule applying?

Comment: don't wanna use `$data = array(
        'update' => array(array(1, 2, 3))
    );` ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I've looked in `Zend_Filter_Input` source, on :1011 it makes field value an array in case if it's not, and `foreach` over it on :1024. So I'm guessing the only solution will be to extend `Zend_Filter_Input`, or wrap value in array as suggested before ?

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd: not yet - haven't found enough time at work

Comment: Your question is another good reason why I created my own IsArray validator class that does a little bit more than just `is_array()`.

Comment: @Adrian World: how would it help in this case? `Zend_Filter_Input` performs recursive traversing, so a particular validator can nothing to do with it

Comment: But it will act like any other validator. Like any other default validator it returns true or false and an error message. Nothing more noting less.

Comment: @Adrian World: I cannot understand how custom validator could help in this case :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed the problem stirs from the callback validator; I jumped on title and didn't pay attention to what you meant with recursive. After doing some tests I can see it now myself and also where the problem actually lies in the filter class. I don't get why they did that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zerkms said :

> Zend_Filter_Input performs recursive traversing, so a
>   particular validator can nothing to do with it.

To solve this problem, I'm using a "durty" way :

```
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input(
    array(
        'the_field_should_be_array'=> array(
             new MyPersonalValidator($this->_request->getParam('the_field_should_be_array')),
         )
    )
);


 class MyPersonalValidator extends Zend_Validate_Abstract{

    private $_paramIsValid;

public function __construct($param)
{
    $this->_paramIsValid = is_array($param);
}

public function isValid($not_usefull)
{
    if(!$this->_paramIsValid)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}}
```

Code explanation : I perform the validation of the field in the constructor of the validator. For this, It's needed to pass the field to the constructor and it not a good pratice but I didn't find another way.

Edit : The clean way is to extend Zend_Filter_Input to support the context. I never new why it wasn't implement before.

Comment: It's too dirty to be used :-) Checking since there will be no other answers